# Expansion of a Polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Let $\mathbf s \in \mathbb N^N$ be a fixed vector, and define the polynomial $a(\cdot)$ such that 
\begin{equation}
a(\mathbf x)=\prod_{i=1}^N\binom{x_i}{s_i}
\end{equation}
for all $\mathbf x \in \mathbb N^N$, where $\binom{x_i}{s_i} = \frac{x_i!}{s_i!(x_i - s_i)!}$.

I'd like to write this polynomial as a linear combination of monomials.  In particular, I'd like to write
\begin{equation}
a(\mathbf x) = \sum_{\mathbf j \in \mathbb N^N} b_\mathbf j \mathbf x^\mathbf j,
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf x^\mathbf j = \prod_{i = 1}^N x_i^{j_i}$, and I have analytical expressions for the each coefficient $b_\mathbf j$ in terms of the vector $\mathbf s$.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: According to Wikipedia's article on binomial coefficients, $\binom{x_i}{s_i}$ can be expanded in terms of "Stirling numbers of the first kind".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: That's probably the key fact I needed.